# Quarkus CDI with custom annotations

Tags: java, cdi, quarkus

I am currently developing an application respecting as much as possible the principles of hexagonal architecture.

Thus, my "domain" module (groupId: `acme` ; artifactId: `my-domain`) does not depend on any technical framework.

All my services are annotated with a custom annotation (itself part of my domain):

```java
package acme.domain;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface DomainService {
}
```

However, in my "Quarkus application" module  (groupId: `acme` ; artifactId: `app-quarkus`), I need to inject services defined in my "domain" module (`acme:domain`).

With SpringBoot, it is [quite easy to inject those domain services (based on a custom annotation)](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-componentscan-filter-type) with the following annotation:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(
    basePackageClasses = {CourtageSpringbootApplication.class, DomainService.class},
    includeFilters = {@ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ANNOTATION, value = {DomainService.class})}
)
public class MySpringbootApplication {
}
```

Is there an equivalent to `@ComponentScan` with Quarkus?

NB : I have added following lines in `app-quarkus/src/main/resources/application.properties` but it does not work:

```
quarkus.index-dependency.courtage.group-id=acme
quarkus.index-dependency.courtage.artifact-id=my-domain
```

Thrown exception: `javax.enterprise.inject.UnsatisfiedResolutionException`

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would personally consider strictly avoiding CDI annotations in your domain module a little bit overzealous. But if you really want that, I can see 2 options:

1. You could limit yourself to only placing CDI annotations on your own annotations, and use `@Stereotype`. For example, if your `@DomainService` should be equivalent to `@ApplicationScoped`, it could be declared like this:

   ```java
   @Stereotype
   @ApplicationScoped
   @Target({ElementType.TYPE})
   @Retention(value = RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface DomainService {
   }
   ```
2. If you absolutely insist that no CDI annotation should ever be present in the domain module, you could create a Quarkus extension that would register `@DomainService` as a custom bean defining annotation. The Quarkus CDI Integration guide has more details about that: https://quarkus.io/guides/cdi-integration You would either use `AutoAddScopeBuildItem` or `BeanDefiningAnnotationBuildItem`.

Comment: It's quite complicated, but I will try your answer.
I recognize that this position (not use CDI annotation in domain) may seem overzealous.
However, I couldn't find a dependency that only contains the needed annotations for CDI.
Example: `@ApplicationScoped` is contained in the dependency: `jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api` which itself depends on `el-api`, which I really don't need.

Comment: I agree with Ladislav in both points. CDI does bring in few other APIs because it comes from an EE background and those were needed to guarantee interoperability. The EL one in particular has been a pain point in several discussions in last years and I agree that it's presence isn't ideal. However, I still think that you could easily depend on CDI API and make your life way simpler for very little cost architecture-wise.

And if you decide not to, then I can confirm that `AutoAddScopeBuildItem` and `BeanDefiningAnnotationBuildItem` are indeed a way to go, albeit not nearly as simple.

Comment: @JYC thanks for your question, we had the same ambitions to keep a hexagonal architecture's "core" module free of any Quarkus dependency, but on the other hand do not really like to have the necessity to manually dependency inject each dep into each other. What does work though is to "only" include the `jakarta.enterprise.cdi-api` dep and exclude all transitive dependencies from that artifact. It compiles and works perfectly fine.  Note that you need to also include the jandex-maven-plugin in your parent pom in order to make Quarkus pickup your beans from the core module.

Answer (score 0):

What an ugly way Spring supplies you for injecting your isolated CDI based domain whereas with CDI standard you would have two ways to add any external CDI beans from a maven dependency into your CDI context during compile-time.

1. using Jandex Index maven plugin:

   org.jboss.jandex
          jandex-maven-plugin
          {jandex-maven-plugin-version}
          
            
              make-index
              
                jandex
2. configuration level (application.yaml):

quarkus:
index-dependency:
courtage:
group-id: org.acme
artifact-id: my-domain